# How MYOB Exonet work? Can I integrate it to my WordPress website?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am totaly new of this term  MYOB Exonet. Can anyone help me to understand this. How it work and how can I integrate  MYOB Exonet to a Australian WordPress website.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're referring to using the [MYOB EXO API](http://developer.myob.com/api/exo/exo-api-overview/).
If you have queries about the MYOB Developer Program you can reach out to the API team via their [contact form](http://developer.myob.com/contact/).

To integrate with a WordPress website you'll need to [build a custom plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) that calls the MYOB EXO API.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @DeveloperJack..It really Helps.